# How can I make all possible list combinations using reversible seeds?

Tags: python, list, random, seed

I want to have a list made out of 100 items, each item being a value from 0-31 inclusive. I then want to be able to take one of these lists, and know what seed/input is necessary to randomly generate that exact list.

Answer (score 0):

### Using some suitable Linear Congruential Generator:

You could use this research paper by Pierre L'Ecuyer:

[Tables_of_linear_congruential_generators_of_different_sizes_and_good_lattice_structure](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Pierre-Lecuyer/publication/220577404_Tables_of_linear_congruential_generators_of_different_sizes_and_good_lattice_structure)

The lowest power of 2 modulus for which the paper gives examples of (decently pseudo-random) [LCGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is 2<sup>30</sup>, which is close to 1 billion. See table 4 of the paper. Just pick one of those LCGs, say:

u<sub>n+1</sub> = ((116646453 * u<sub>n</sub>) + 5437)  mod 2<sup>30</sup>

Each of your items is exactly 5 bits wide. If you decide to group your items 6 by 6, each *group* is exactly 30 bits wide, so can be considered as one state of this modulo 2<sup>30</sup> LCG.

From a initial group of 6 items, one step of the LCG will generate the next group, that is the next 6 items. And the paper tells you that the serie will look reasonably random overall.

Hence, you can regard the first 6 items as your “seed”, as you can reconstruct the whole list from its leftmost 6 items.

Even assuming that for the sake of obfuscation you started the visible part of the list *after* the seed, you would still have only about one billion possible seeds to worry about. Any decent computer would be able to find the left-hidden seed by brute force within a handful of seconds, by simulating the LCG for every possible seed and comparing with the actual list.

### Sample Python code:

One can start by creating a class that, given a  seed, supplies an unlimited serie of items between 0 and 31:

```
class LEcuyer30:
   def  __init__ (self, seed):
       self.seed      = seed & ((1 << 30) - 1)
       self.currGroup = self.seed
       self.itemCount = 6

   def __toNextGroup(self):
       nextGroup = ((116646453 * self.currGroup) + 5437) % (1 << 30)
       self.currGroup = nextGroup
       self.itemCount = 6

   def  getItem(self):
       if (self.itemCount <= 0):
           self.__toNextGroup()

       # extract 5 bits:
       word = self.currGroup >> (5 * (self.itemCount - 1))
       self.itemCount -= 1
       return (word & 31)
```

### Test code:

We can create a sequence of 20 items and print it:

```
# Main program:

randomSeed = 514703103
rng = LEcuyer30(randomSeed)

itemList = []
for k in range(20):
    item = rng.getItem()
    itemList.append(item)

print("itemList = %s" % itemList)
```

### Program output:

```
itemList = [15, 10, 27, 15, 23, 31, 1, 10, 5, 15, 16, 8, 4, 16, 24, 31, 7, 5, 8, 19]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I will start looking into this method. Also how would I format that formula into a python script?

Comment: @James - see added Python code at the end of my answer. You should have given a [Python] tag to your question if such a thing as *Python* code was desired. This is how you attract a suitable readership. Good luck.

Comment: @James - In fact, the Python tag is required if the SO web site is to understand that Python syntax coloring is appropriate. Otherwise, the code appears as flatly black and white, a hint that something is definitely amiss.